# Prove that in the union of two trees there exist a vertex with degree of at most $3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> Let $T_1=(V, E_1), T_2=(V,E_2)$ be trees on the same set of vertices, and let $G=(V,E_1 \cup E_2)$ be the graph resulting from the union of the two trees. Prove that there exist a vertex with degree of at most $3$.

My attempt, suppose that for all $v\in G, d(v)>3$, so the easy cases are if $G$ is a tree or has leafs.

Trying to show that there is a vertex such that $d(v)=2$, since both $T_{1,2}$ are trees, that means they must have leafs, if we have a connection between a leaf in $T_1$ to any point in $T_2$, then that leaf has a degree of $2$ in $G$.

I can't find a way prove that there's a vertex with a degree $3$ though...

Also, I just saw this: [Prove that in two trees with same vertices there exists a vertex that the sum of its' degree in both trees is maximum $3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401047/prove-that-in-two-trees-with-same-vertices-there-exists-a-vertex-that-the-sum-of)

I don't understand why $\sum d(v)\ge 4n$? shouldn't that be $2n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the answer to the earlier question **TheNotMe** is using the hypothesis that $d_G(v)>3$ for each $v\in V$. Thus, $d_G(v)\ge 4$ for each $v\in V$, and $\sum_{v\in V}d_G(v)\ge 4n$, since $|V|=n$.

Comment: I see now. Is my approach even close though? Is it right to try to show each of the three cases?

Comment: @kuhaku: I’ve not thought very hard about it, but I strongly suspect that it would be difficult to make your approach work: it looks like the cases and subcases will get very complicated.